# how to count numbers of the client behind NAT

Tags: networking, client, nat, behind

recently I'm learning about NAT and want to count the number of the client behind NAT, 
is there any way to figure out how many endpoint systems are using the NAT router?

Answer (score 0):

if there is a firewall in the network, there is no way to count the number of client behind NAT from outside.